# Usage of Chartjs in Angular2 App

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, chart.js

I am currently exploring Angular2 in combination with TypeScript and I would like to include the Chartjs module in my application. In the [chartjs documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) is shown how to do it using the common canvas html tag:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {[...]});
</script>
```

How can I do similar things with Angular2 and TypeScript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use npm module:

[angular2-chartjs](https://github.com/emn178/angular2-chartjs)

Then you can use it like this in your module:

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-chartjs';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ChartModule ]
  // ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And in html template:

```
<chart [type]="type" [data]="data" [options]="options"></chart>
```

Don't forget to fill it with data ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
<canvas #myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
`)}
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('myChart') myChart;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var myChart = new Chart(this.target.nativeElement, {[...]});
  }
}
```